# How do I check the number of token holders?

Tags: erc-20

I would like to know how many people own the erc20 tokens I created.

Is there a way to check through the api?
Or please tell me another good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your token is emitting logs correctly, Etherscan's Holders tab should show the info. See for example [USDC](https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#balances): "Top 1,000 holders (From a total of 1,483,388 holders)".

Comment: I want to check through the api, not from Etherscan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use api to fetch the token holders data.
https://docs.chainbase.com/reference/gettokenholders
here is the node.js code example
Using fetch in JavaScript.

```
network_id = '1'; // See https://docs.chainbase.com/reference/supported-chains to get the id of different chains.
token_addr = '0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0'; // Take MATIC token address as an example.

fetch(`https://api.chainbase.online/v1/token/holders?chain_id=${network_id}&contract_address=${token_addr}&page=1&limit=20`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': CHAINBASE_API_KEY, // Replace the field with your API key.
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Using axios in JavaScript. You need to install axios using npm install axios --save in the terminal first.

```
network_id = '1'; // See https://docs.chainbase.com/reference/supported-chains to get the id of different chains.
token_addr = '0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0'; // Take MATIC token address as an example.

const axios = require('axios');
const options = {
    url: `https://api.chainbase.online/v1/token/holders?chain_id=${network_id}&contract_address=${token_addr}&page=1&limit=20`,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': CHAINBASE_API_KEY, // Replace the field with your API key.
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
};
axios(options)
    .then(response => console.log(response.data.data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

To better leverage the ability that Chainbase provides, you can register [here](https://chainbase.com/) for a free [account](https://chainbase.com/blog/article/how-to-register-a-chainbase-account) and access to different APIs and data cloud.

After logging into Chainbase, visit the dashboard to get an overview. Create a new project in the console and get an API key.